# How to find release date of any .rpm before installing it

Tags: linux, rpm

Is there any way to get the release date (via command line) of an RPM without downloading or installing it?

I can get detailed information via the command below but can't find the release date of that particular RPM:

```
[root@connect ~]# yum info kernel-2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
Available Packages
Name        : kernel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.6.32
Release     : 642.6.2.el6
Size        : 32 M
Repo        : updates
Summary     : The Linux kernel
URL         : http://www.kernel.org/
License     : GPLv2
Description : The kernel package contains the Linux kernel (vmlinuz), the core of any
            : Linux operating system.  The kernel handles the basic functions
            : of the operating system: memory allocation, process allocation, device
            : input and output, etc.
```

Comment: just check  date and timestamp of files of rpm packages when you installed rpm packages.That didnt change to current timestamp and date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl -I http://vault.centos.org/6.8/updates/Source/SPackages/kernel-2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.src.rpm 2>&1 | grep Last-Modified
```

Returns:

```
Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 07:31:10 GMT
```

Use the address of the RPM you want to check, and you have your answer without downloading or installing it.